# Errors during compilation: in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, shipment, override-model

I am overriding `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment` due to some custom work in pdf shipment by using preference

Below is the `di.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment"/>
</config>
```

and `DefaultShipment file` is

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment;

/**
 * Sales Order Shipment Pdf default items renderer
 */
class DefaultShipment extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment
{
    /**
     * Core string
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
     */
    protected $string;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->string = $string;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $taxData,
            $filesystem,
            $filterManager,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Draw item line
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function draw()
    {
        
        $item = $this->getItem();
        $pdf = $this->getPdf();
        $page = $this->getPage();
        $lines = [];


       
        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = [
            [
                // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
                'text' => $this->string->split(html_entity_decode($item->getName()), 60, true, true),
                'feed' => 100
            ]
        ];

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 35];

        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = [
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
            'text' => $this->string->split(html_entity_decode($this->getSku($item)), 25),
            'feed' => 565,
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // Custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = [
                    'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 70, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 110,
                ];

                // draw options value
                if ($option['value'] !== null) {
                    $printValue = isset(
                        $option['print_value']
                    ) ? $option['print_value'] : $this->filterManager->stripTags(
                        $option['value']
                    );
                    $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 50, true, true), 'feed' => 115];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $this->setPage($page);
    }
}
```

When compiling the code, getting below error:

> Errors during compilation:

```
Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Shipment\DefaultShipment Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
```

I am not getting what argument causing the issue. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the parent constructor arguments. Whenever write the preference, make sure the order of the arguments in `parent::__construct()` should be same as the parent class file. So change the parent constructor arguments as below:

```
parent::__construct(
    $context,
    $registry,
    $taxData,
    $filesystem,
    $filterManager,
    $string,
    $resource,
    $resourceCollection,
    $data
);
```

Comment: the solution is working fine, but I am strange why override file changes are not getting reflecting, still core file code reflected, Could you please check what be the issue?